# Which cardinality must the image of a countable set of functions have to separate the points in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

Let $F=\{f_i:(0,1)\to X\}$ be a countable set of functions where $X$ is some arbitrary set. I am interested in the cardinality of $X$ that is needed to find an $F$ which separates the points in $(0,1)$.

1. Is a finite $X$ sufficient?
2. Is a finite $X$ sufficient if the preimages $\bigcup_i f_i^{-1}(x)$ shall be measurable sets in $(0,1)$ for all $x\in X$?

Is the following a valid answer to the first question?
$X=\{0,\ldots,9\}$ and $f_i(r)=\text{``i-th component in the decimal expansion of r''} $.

I guess that for the second question $X$ must be uncountable, but I have no idea how I would prove this.

Many thanks!

Comment: In fact you can use $X=\{0,1\}$ by considering binary expansions. And measurability is no problem; the preimages _are_ measurable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the ignorant question: By measurable, I meant Lebesgue measurable; how do I see that the preimages are Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Each of those preimages is a finite union of intervals.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: Another simple solution would be $$f_r(t) = \begin{cases}0& t \le r\\1 & t> r\end{cases}$$ for all rational $r \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks!